# Are moves automatically used when reassigning to the mapped variable?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I implement a new interface for `sort`

```
vector<int> sort(vector<int> in){
  //sorting logic
}
```

And use it like this

```
vector<int> some_integers = {2, 1, 3};
some_integers = sort(some_integers);
```

Will the compiler automatically move `some_integers`? Or will it copy?

Comment: Use `some_integers = sort(std::move(some_integers));` to not have any copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment is moved (because the function returns a prvalue), the argument is copied (because it is an lvalue).